# Guice multi database auto switch

Tags: java, guice

I have three database cofinguration

1. local db for unit test environment
2. test db for development environment
3. online db for product environment

How Can I automatic inject  different db properties according to environment ?

> By using xml with spring,  I can use maven profiles and Resources
>   filter feature to have this work done.

What 's the solution with guice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case you can use `binder.bindConstant()` within your `Module` like this:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("user.name")).to(System.getProperty("user.name"));
```

You use this like this:

```
@Inject @Named("user.name")
private String userName;
```

How you set the system properties at the start of the program is up to you.

Another but similar way is the utility method `cNames.bindProperties(Binder, Map<String, String>)` where you can set arbitrary properties in one go.

Comment: Shall I pass -Duser.name when I start jvm?

Comment: @jilen That's a possible way.

Comment: but if I am using the Jetty/Tomcat, I don't want to change jetty.sh/startup.sh really. how do I pass the environment to my app?

Comment: How would the maven profile which you have mentioned, work? I assume by loading some given property file and putting that into the spring-context. So you do the same with guice. But you have to load the property file by yourself and put that into the `Map<String, String>` I have mentioned in the code.

Comment: I use mvn clean package -Prelease/-Pdevelopment to active profile. And set release profile actived by default!

Comment: maven can filter xml with properties file, I use profile to choose which properties to use when I am doing package. But guice have no xml.